# 'sa' user is "pinging" my Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql, azure, audit, cdata, sa

I have a Azure SQL Database with Auditing turned on. I noticed that my database comes online after a pause when it shouldn't. I checked the audit logs and it shows strange entries of 'sa' login trying to do smth. Not sure what these entries mean. Is a normal activity from Azure or somebody is trying to connect to my database? I believe that there is no such user 'sa' on Azure SQL databases, or am I wrong. Attaching the screenshot of audit logs.

Additional_info column shows these values (they repeat for every event).

> <action_info xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/sqlaudit_data">destroyed</action_info>
> <action_info xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/sqlaudit_data">event disabled</action_info>
> <action_info xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/sqlaudit_data">event enabled<startup_type>automatic</startup_type></action_info>

[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcxWH.jpg)

Tried Google, found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I created azure SQL database in azure portal, and I enabled auditing server level destination as storage account.
Image for reference:

[image]

After that I enabled auditing at database level with same destination of storage account.
Image for reference:

[image]

It enabled successfully, and containers are created successfully in storage account.

Image for reference:

[image]

Audit Records:

[image]

Here is my [log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4g0o.png)
In this way I am not getting any error related to sa user.
As per my knowledge sa user is the admin you created during setup of SQL Azure server
According to [this](https://www.sqlshack.com/automatic-pause-and-resume-an-azure-sql-database/)
Once the azure database is in pause status, it resumes automatically in the following conditions:

- Database connection
- database export or copy
- Viewing auditing records
- Viewing or applying performance recommendation
- Vulnerability assessment
- Modifying or viewing data masking rules
- View state for transparent data encryption
- Modification for serverless configuration such as max vCores, min vCores, or auto-pause delay

May be for above reason database still remains in online when you pause it.